# I am getting invalid string like android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText while getting edittext value

Tags: java, android

Here is my java fragment code

```
    public class A_AssignExam extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
        EditText username;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            username=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.usernameeditassignexam);
            Log.d("Username------>", ""+username);
    }
```

I get the following error message

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {52750c5c VFED..CL ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d00d8 app:id/usernameeditassignexam}
org.veetech.veeknowintern D/Username------>: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {52750c5c VFED..CL ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d00d8 app:id/usernameeditassignexam}
org.veetech.veeknowintern D/Username------>: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {52750c5c VFED..CL .F. ..... 152,0-572,90 #7f0d00d8 app:id/usernameeditassignexam}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the class/instance as returned by `toString` by default instead you need to do

```
Log.d("Username------>", username.getText().toString());
```

If you don't already know - the same problem is why you are having to do `"" +` -  This is because if you did `Log.d(TAG, username);` it would tell you the signature does not match - it does not know what to do with this Object 'EditText'. By concatenating it with an emtpy string you're saying treat this object as a string too, so Java casts it by calling the `toString` method of the object. In the future you'll be able recognise this as a signal you're using the object by accident instead of its value

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
Log.d("Username------>", username.getText().toString());
```

`.toString()` is needed when you want a `String`. 
Because `.getText()` returns `CharSequence`.

Comment: What is this? OP used `username`, not `username.getText()`.

Comment: "username" is the class EditText type, which have method getText() which will return the text which user typed into widget.

Without this call, he get only instance to whole EditText

Comment: and how is this different from the other answer?

Comment: I wroted it at the same time as NC.